# how to compare elements row and column based when we have elements as a list?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataFrame and each column is a list with 3 elements. How I can compare the second element os each list based on each column and row based?

```
Col1   col2    col3
['A',0.2,5]  ['A',0.4,5]  ['A',0,5]
['A',0.4,5]  ['A',0.2,5]  ['A',0.7,5]
['A',0.1,5]  ['A',0.1,5]  ['A',0.20,5]
['A',0.25,5]  ['A',0.9,5]  ['A',0.22,5]
```

max of the second element in column based:

```
col1=0.4
col2=0.9
col3=0.22
```

max of the second element in row based:

```
 row1=0.2
row2=0.7
row3=0.20
row4=0.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
def mymax(x):
    return max([y[1] for y in x])

df.apply(mymax)
df.apply(mymax, axis=1)
```

---

**EDIT**

The following code tries to give an answer to the below OP comment:

```
def imax(x):
    return np.argmax([y[1] for y in x])

df.apply(imax)
df.apply(imax, axis=1)

# in case, we want the column names
df.columns[df.apply(imax, axis=1)].tolist()
```

Comment: is there any way to get the index of the max column and row? like `argmax`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `applymap` to extract the second element from the lists and then use `axis` to get the max in the columns or the rows:

```
new_df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[1])
# rows
new_df.max(axis=1)
# columns
new_df.max()
```

Comment: is there any way to get the index of the max column and row? like argmax?

Answer (score 1):

For a vectorial solution, you can `stack`, slice, then `groupby.max` on the desired level.

#### For rows:

```
df.stack().str[1].groupby(level=0).max()
```

Output:

```
0    0.4
1    0.7
2    0.2
3    0.9
dtype: float64
```

#### For columns:

```
df.stack().str[1].groupby(level=1).max()
```

Output:

```
Col1    0.4
col2    0.9
col3    0.7
dtype: float64
```

Comment: is it possible I can get the max index too? for example `0.4` is for the second column.

Comment: @user15649753 just use `idxmax` in place of `max`